# In React Native can I setState to an object that is in an api call?

Tags: react-native, api, setstate

This should be something so incredibly easy, but I'm struggling really hard on this. All I want to do is setState of **id** to "results.id" from my api call. Once it changes the state to what is inside of the api, I will then be able to successfully open up the filmography api. I've tested the axios fetch url by putting in a real id, and it works. So I'm basically trying to grab the id that I get from a search, and update the id state with THAT id. If I'm trying to setState in the wrong function, then by all means help me get it in the right function! (Also I know I have some sloppy code, but a lot of it is personal notes for me until I'm ready to save it for good)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Screen4() {
  // id is a 2 digit number for specific actor const apiurl5 = "http://api.tmdb.org/3/search/person?api_key=84c329a92566be57845322a19ff707ac&query=" const apiurl4 = "/movie_credits?api_key=84c329a92566be57845322a19ff707ac&language=en-US" const apiurl3 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/" const apiurl2 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=84c329a92566be57845322a19ff707ac&language=en-US&page=1"; const apiurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=7ad73765&"; const [state, setState] = useState({ s: "Enter an actor...", id: "", results: [], selected: [], modalVisible: false, modalVisible2: false });

  const search = () => {
    // apiurl + "&t=" + state.s (Single Result)
    // apiurl + "&s=" + state.s (Multiple Results)
    axios(apiurl5 + state.s).then(({ data }) => {
      //let results = [data]; ----- ******** Use this for &t= **************** -------------
      //let results = data.Search; ----- ******** Use this for &s= **************** -------------
      let results = data.results;
      let id = state.id;

      setState((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, modalVisible: true };
      }),
        setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, results: results };
        }),
        setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, id: id };
        }),
        Alert.alert("The ID is: ", id, [
          { text: "Close", onPress: () => console.log("alert closed") },
        ]);
    });
  };

  const openPopup = () => {
    axios(apiurl3 + state.id + apiurl4).then(({ data }) => {
      let result = data.cast;

      setState((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, modalVisible2: true };
      }),
        setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, selected: result };
        });
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10, justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Cinemaster!</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: "#ff0000",
          marginBottom: 20,
        }}
        onChangeText={(text) =>
          setState((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, s: text };
          })
        }
        onSubmitEditing={search}
        value={state.s}
      />
      <Button onPress={search} title="Search"></Button>
      {/* key=result.imdbID - 
                                    This gives multiple search results with the &s= is in the URL

                                    key=result -
                                    This gives the result with the &t= is in the URL */}
      <Modal
        //animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        //visible={(state.modalVisible)}
        animationIn="slideInRight"
        animationOut="slideOutLeft"
        useNativeDriver={true}
        isVisible={state.modalVisible}
      >
        <ScrollView>
          {state.results.map((results, index) => (
            <TouchableHighlight key={index}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10, justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Button title="Full Filmography" onPress={openPopup}></Button>

                <Text>Gender: {results.gender}</Text>
                <Text>ID: {results.id}</Text>

                {results.known_for.map((k, i) => (
                  <TouchableHighlight
                    key={i}
                    // onPress={() => openPopup()}
                  >
                    <View>
                      <Text>Title: {k.title}</Text>
                      <Image
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/" +
                            k.poster_path,
                        }}
                        style={{ width: 300, height: 500 }}
                        resizeMode="cover"
                      />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                ))}

                {/* <Text>Title: {results.gender}</Text> -----THIS ALSO WORKS----- */}

                {/* {dataItems.map((item, index) => (
                                    <div key={index}>
                                        <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                                        {item.content.map((c, i) => (
                                        <div key={i}>
                                            <img src={c.imageUrl} />
                                            <h3>{c.title}</h3>
                                            <h3>{c.description}</h3>
                                            <hr />
                                        </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                    ))} */}
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          ))}

          <Text
            onPress={() =>
              setState((prevState) => {
                return { ...prevState, modalVisible: false };
              })
            }
            style={{
              marginTop: 50,
              color: "red",
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            Close!
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </Modal>

      {/* animationType in Modal can be fade, none, or slide */}
      <Modal
        //animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        //visible={(state.modalVisible)}
        animationIn="slideInRight"
        animationOut="slideOutLeft"
        useNativeDriver={true}
        isVisible={state.modalVisible2}
      >
        <ScrollView>
          {state.selected.map((cast, index2) => (
            <View key={index2}>
              <Text>Title:{cast.title} </Text>
              <Text>Overview:{cast.overview} </Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() =>
            setState((prevState) => {
              return { ...prevState, modalVisible2: false };
            })
          }
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              marginTop: 50,
              color: "red",
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            Close!
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

API for results.id :
http://api.tmdb.org/3/search/person?api_key=84c329a92566be57845322a19ff707ac&query=tom%20hanks

API for filmography:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/31/movie_credits?api_key=84c329a92566be57845322a19ff707ac&language=en-US

Attached an image, showing the ID I'm trying to setState in[PhoneExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiBpg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to use a for loop in order to get the data I needed in order to then set that data. What wasn't clear to me at first, was if that was necessary or not, and if it was I assumed I had to do that in the section of my code where I was mapping things. But no, once I got a for loop going in that search function it started to make sense to me.